woocommerce вернуть кол-во товаров на странице по кнопке
У меня в woocommerce 10 товаров с помощью хука и небольшого кода можно показать на первой странице 9 товаров, на второй следующие 9 и т.д. код работает
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'truemisha_products_per_page', 20 );
    function truemisha_products_per_page( $col ) {  
    $col = 9;
    return $col;    
    }

дальше на моей странице есть кнопки, показать на странице 3 товара, 5 и 9
<form method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="test" value="9" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="test1" value="5" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="test2" value="3" /><br/>
        </form>

и следующий код:
function truemisha_products_per_page( $col1 ) {
$col = 4;
if(array_key_exists('test2',$_POST)){
    $col = 3;
}
if(array_key_exists('test1',$_POST)){
    $col = 5;
}
if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
$col= 9;
}
$col1=$col;
return $col1;
}

изначально 4 товара на странице, на второй следующие 4 и т.д.
я нажимаю на кнопку 3 и 3 товара на странице, но как только я перемещаюсь на другую страницу снова 4 товара на странице, почему не 3 ? и как сделать так, чтобы на всех на страницах было по три товара при нажатии на копку 3
